# Connect to remote database in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I am trying to build an asp.net core mvc application.
I have an already existing remote database on this website that provides free sql server
https://www.freesqldatabase.com/

when I created the database I have recieved an email with credentials of the db
Host: sql6.freesqldatabase.com
Database name: sql6455969
Database user: sql6455969
Database password: pass
Port number: 3306

Now I am trying to connect to it but it gives me this error
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error.

This is the code in appsettings.json file

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"APDBConnection": "Server = sql6.freesqldatabase.com,3306; Database = sql6455969; User Id = sql6455969; Password = pass;"
 },
```

code in startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("APDBConnection")
            )
        );
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
```

I don't know what is the problem with the connection

Thanks to Ian's answer I have found that I should use UseMySql instead of UseSqlServer and install Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql packet

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("APDBConnection")
            )
        );
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `tcp:` prefix to the server name, as [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#remarks) suggests?

Comment: Yes. I have tried and it gives the same error @RichardDeeming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be really great if you'd read the actual website:

> Currently we offer **MySQL** with plans to launch further database platforms with multiple platforms including the latest releases.

MySQL is not MSSQL.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean with MySQL is not MSSQL

Comment: SQL Server is Microsoft SQL Server. MySQL is an Oracle product. The two are not the same.

Comment: Thank you I have noticed that from your answer and tried to find solution